# How to play a video in an Unity WebGL build on iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, video-player, unity-webgl

I try this for hours but I can't get it to work. Nothing really special:

Unity WebGL build running on iOS on an iPhone (safari/chrome). It's just a Play-Button an a RenderTexture to render the clip.

The VideoPlayer component looks like this, also nothing special:

[image: videoplayer component]

Everything works fine on MacOS Safari/Chrome, Android Phones with Chrome Browser or Windows.

Only iOS Devices will not play the clip.

Any suggestions what I could do?

Thanks!
Stephan

Comment: Unity creates html video element for playing video in web browsers. You can create a simple html page with video element and test your video on iOS devices. Maybe video format is not supported by Safari